# Does Yoshi have a saddle or a shell on his back?

Tags: super-mario-brothers

[image]

In most older incarnations of Yoshi, he had what appeared to be a saddle on his back, which Mario would ride on in games like Super Mario World. Now newer 3D renditions show this to actually be a red shell. Do we know for sure whether it was meant to be a saddle or a shell?

Comment: Yoshi on the right is younger than Yoshi on the left.  Yoshi on the left has clearly been through a few too many of Mario's ground-pounds.

Comment: I'm super surprised this wasn't posted on Arqade.

Comment: Shell-shaped saddle?

Comment: @Ash Arqade doesn't allow backstory questions

Comment: @TheAsh it does, in some cases, actually.

Comment: In Mario Kart Tour, Yoshi counts as a "driver wearing a shell" for challenges that have such a character as a requirement.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to *[Super Mario History](http://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Mario_History)*, it's a saddle that was originally a shell during development.

> Yoshi was originally supposed to be a type of Koopa. That saddle you see on his back was actually his shell. - Takashi Tezuka

The official German Club Nintendo magazine apparently also refered to it as a saddle, but I can't confirm it.

Translated from German:

> He's wearing jump boots and he has a saddle on his back. He's green and very hungry. He's a dinosaur and Mario's best friend. He's good, because he's YOSHI!!!

Comment: *"He's good, because he's YOSHI!!!"* Quite possibly the video game quote of the decade!

Comment: @RLH And then Luigi reads the "best friend" part and does a spit-take.

Comment: Good point, but Luigi IS his brother.  Blood tends to be thicker than water, as they say, so Luigi may not be that offended.  He's seems pretty cool. B-)

Comment: @RLH "Fun" fact! `The blood of the covenant is thicker than the water of the womb` originally meant exactly the opposite of what the shorter version means today.

Comment: @EngineerToast, fun fact, every time someone mentions the blood and water thing, there will always be at least one person there to mention the supposedly original quote and its inverse meaning.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez This is the first I've heard either fun fact.

Comment: @RLH "He's good, because he's YOSHI!" is because "yosh" is a Japanese expression of excitement meaning "okay!" or "all right!".

Comment: Yoshi is a she..

Comment: Could you add the original German from which it's translated?

Comment: @christian The source I found didn't have it, unfortunately.

Comment: @RogueJedi Could you reference the source from which you took the claim?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez All the more fun given there's no evidence the *English* idiom is in fact derived from that "full" version; rather our earliest sources on the latter present it as a *contrasting view*.